# Reading multiple json values with php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to read certain values from a json string in php, I am able to do a simple json string with only one value such as

```
$json = '{"value":"somevalue"}';
```

Using this:

```
<?php 
      $json = '{"value":"somevalue"}';
      $obj = json_decode(json_encode($json));
      print $obj->{'value'};
?>
```

But when i try an get a value from the following json string it throws an error...

```
$json = '{"field": "title","rule": {"required": "true","minlength": "4","maxlength": "150" }}';
```

I validated the json on JSONlint but not sure how to access the values within this with php.

- Thanks

Comment: What error does it throw, and what's the code that throws it?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\wamp\www\l\public\grr.php</b> on line <b>21

Comment: you are trying to access an array like an object. use `$obj['value']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$json = '{"field": "title","rule": {"required": "true","minlength": "4","maxlength": "150" }}'; 
//since $json is a  valid json format you needn't encode and decode it again
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r($obj->filed);
print_r($obj->rule);
```

Comment: @jason,please don't always leave your questions an unanswered state,and that would be some kinda of negative record.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `true` as a second parameter to `json_decode()` to get the results as an array

```
$my_arr = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($my_arr);
```

Should help you. You can then step through the array as you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

use `var_dump` to print out the object with all it's members and hierarchy. you should then be able to find the value you are looking for

Comment: thats not my problem, I can print out all the values but i am unable to access one of the values:



<pre>

$json = '{"field": "title","rule": {"required": "true","minlength": 
"4","maxlength": "150" }}';
$json = json_encode($json);

$obj = json_decode($json,true);

print $obj -> {'field'};

</pre>

**
Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\wamp\www\l\public\grr.php</b> on line <b>21
**

Comment: If you pass `true` to `json_decode()`, it'll give you back an array, not an object. You need to access elements in the way you normally would for an array.

Comment: @jason First, please do not post code in comment fields, it's messy. :) Second, when using `json_decode(..., true)`, the result is indeed not an object, but an array. Yet you're trying to access it like an object. The error message is quite correct.